# Unable to assign values to array within -exec command of find result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have the following command written to assign find results into an array, to delete files older than 7 days later.

```
F_ARR[0]=''
unset F_ARR
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -exec sh -c '
    for pathname; do
        F_ARR+=("$pathname")
    done' sh {} +
echo ${#F_ARR[@]}
```

But, when I print the length of array F_ARR, it shows 0. Did I commit something wrong in code?

Comment: array values can not share across  different sub-shell,  the ```find -exec``` create a sub-shell where you assigned the value, it did not , and it can not pass to the outer shell

Comment: in fact i am not following the code int the find command, why is it necessary? ```find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7```  print out every dir older than 7 days by default

Comment: I was just trying to capture the files I am going to delete in the same shell. since I used ` ! -type d ` I am capturing the files older than +7 days.

Comment: to confirm : you want the filenames before actually delete them ?

Comment: Yes. And also, simillarly I am capturing directories before I delete them in another part of the code. why because if I delete files first, the mtime of the directory is chaning. So, in a similar way abvoe, I was capturing directories older than 7 days and then trying to delte files followed by directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'sh code' {} +
```

From within your bash/ksh shell, runs a `find` command in a new process which runs one or more `sh` command invocation. The `sh code` will only be able to affect variables of the `sh` invocation that interprets that code (by the way, `sh` is not meant to support arrays).

If you want to store the paths of the files found by `find` into an array of the current shell, it's that shell that has to perform the assignment.

With `bash` 4.4+, you could do it with:

```
readarray -td '' F_ARR < <(find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -print0)
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-print0`, you can replace it with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`.

(with older versions of `bash`, see [how you can do it in this answer to a similar question](/a/362446)).

Here, you could also use the `zsh` shell instead and do:

```
f_arr=($CDIR/**/*(NDm+7^/))
```

The differences from the above would be that:

- the list of files is sorted, you can add the `oN` glob qualifier to disable sorting
- `$CDIR` itself won't be included even if it's over 8 days old.
- if `$CDIR` is a symlink to a directory, `zsh` will still descend into it.

Since you're tagging your question with both `bash` and `ksh`, note that there are different implementations and variants of ksh (ksh88, ksh93, the upcoming ksh2020 for the ones (initially) by David Korn, pdksh and its derivatives like OpenBSD `sh` or `mksh`, to which you could add zsh's ksh emulation mode).

Most of `bash` features do come from `ksh88` and `ksh93`, a few from `zsh` and `mksh`. `readarray` is one of the few features that is native to `bash` and not found elsewhere.

ksh93 did add a `-d` option to `read` in 1993, later copied by bash (2000) zsh (2003) and mksh (2011), but only bash, zsh, mksh and ksh2020 can use it with an empty delimiter to process NUL delimited records. Process substitution was added in ksh86 (1986), but none of the pdksh-based variants of ksh support it, so the methods mentioned above for old versions of `bash` won't  work in any version of ksh (except zsh's ksh emulation mode).

In ksh88, ksh93 and pdksh-based shells, one option is to post-process the output of `find` so it generates the shell code that can define that array and evaluate that code with `eval`:

```
eval set -A F_ARR "$(
  LC_ALL=C find "$CDIR" ! -type d -exec awk -v q="'" -- '
    BEGIN {
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf " %s", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      exit
    }' {} +
)"
```

(here assuming `$CDIR` doesn't start with `+` or `-`. If it may, with some `ksh` implementations, you can use `set -A F_ARR --`. In any case, if it starts with `-`, `find` will choke on it).

That same approach could be use for any POSIX sh by replacing `set -A F_ARR` with `set --`, which would then populate the one array of POSIX shells: `"$@"`.

Comment: Thank youf for the answer. I am getting below error in bash. Kindly help. `-bash: readarray: -d: invalid option`

Comment: @SrinivasaraoKotipatruni, when I say bash 4.4+, that means bash version 4.4 or above. You must have an older version.

Comment: okay. Thank you. mine is 4.2

Comment: @SrinivasaraoKotipatruni, see edit for older versions of bash.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected — see the [manpage](http://www.mirbsd.org/man1/mksh) for details, e.g. this quote `All commands of a pipeline are executed in separate subshells`, and the following FAQ entry:

```
   Something is going wrong with my while...read loop
     Most likely, you've encountered the problem in which the shell runs all
     parts of a pipeline as subshell.  The inner loop will be executed in a
     subshell and variable changes cannot be propagated if run in a pipeline:

           bar | baz | while read foo; do ...; done

     Note that exit in the inner loop will only exit the subshell and not the
     original shell.  Likewise, if the code is inside a function, return in
     the inner loop will only exit the subshell and won't terminate the func‐
     tion.

     Use co-processes instead:

           bar | baz |&
           while read -p foo; do ...; done
           exec 3>&p; exec 3>&-

     If read is run in a loop such as while read foo; do ...; done then lead‐
     ing whitespace will be removed (IFS) and backslashes processed.  You
     might want to use while IFS= read -r foo; do ...; done for pristine I/O.
     Similarly, when using the -a option, use of the -r option might be pru‐
     dent (“read -raN-1 arr <file”); the same applies for NUL-terminated
     lines:

           find . -type f -print0 |& \
               while IFS= read -d '' -pr filename; do
                   print -r -- "found <${filename#./}>"
           done
```

So, let’s convert your code (also replaced the first two lines with one that properly clears the array):

```
set -A F_ARR
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -print0 |&
while IFS= read -d '' -pr pathname; do
        F_ARR+=("$pathname")
done
echo ${#F_ARR[@]}
```

This requires a [find(1)](http://www.mirbsd.org/man1/find) that supports the `-print0` option, and a recent enough `mksh` on the execution side to support `-d ''` for NUL-terminated lines. If your Korn Shell is older, do it without (but then it would not support `+=(…)` either, so chances are it’s recent enough).

Full disclosure: I’m the [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) developer.

Answer (score 0):

i think for a  while and decided that mostly preserve your way of coding
 i am not faimilar with ksh so i have to code in bash
sorry if you need to translate

a temporary file is needed
because `for` and  `while` both spawns sub-shell in  pipelines , therefore can not pass out array values

you can change the file pattern , so that `mktemp` place the temp file in a directory that you will not need to process
replace the echo part in while loop to your code

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
tmp=`mktemp /tmp/findingXXXXXX`
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 |awk '{print "F_ARR["(NR-1)"]="$0}' >$tmp
. $tmp
rm -f $tmp
while [ "${F_ARR[$i]}" != "" ];
  do
      echo i=$i ${F_ARR[$i]}
      ((i++))

done
```